# refinerycms-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, refinerycms

I followed this [tutorial](http://sdownie.com/articles/refinerycms-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-app) and getting this error, there is another [question](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2406) but i didn't get how the problem was solved

```
NoMethodError in Refinery::Admin::DashboardController#index

undefined method `signup_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0xb53f79dc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you're trying to use the new version of Refinery 2.1 and the article was written for Refinery 2.0.  There were updates to config/initializers/refinery/user.rb which can be found here https://gist.github.com/sdownie/6843871.  I've updates the article so you shouldn't run into any more problems if you go though it again.  The updated tutorial can be found here: http://sdownie.com/articles/refinerycms-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-app